# Cannot create CCSprite with subfolder png when port to Android application with cocos2d-x?

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I met the problem I cannot create CCSprite in cocos2d-x Android.

I have a xml file which store the file path. And I read the file path to create a Sprite. The Sprite is NULL.

```
CCSprite* pSprite1 = CCSprite::create(tempfilename.c_str());
```

tempfilename contains `withword\\stone_0.png`.All my resources is located under `assets\..`,and this png is located under `assets\withword\stone_0.png`. I don't know why I cannot create this sprite. How can I solve this problem?

I have checked [this topic](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/forums/6/topics/31739) but still don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add sub directories to your search path in cocos-2dx, 
You can do this in your `AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching()` method before loading any scene.

```
int i = 0;
CCFileUtils *fileUtils = CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils();
std::vector<std::string> searchPaths = fileUtils->getSearchPaths();
searchPaths.insert(searchPaths.begin() + i++, "withword");
fileUtils->setSearchPaths(searchPaths);
```

Comment: It is really a stupid mistake, I changed `withword\stone_0.png` to `withword/stone_0.png`. Everything is OK. Really thanks for your answer.

Comment: Ok, but I think better approach would be using search path for sub-directories and you don't need to use full file path when loading it to avoid possible errors. You can use like `CCSprite::create("stone_0.png");`