# Errors with assets read and write porting cocos2d-x win32 project to Android?

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

Now I put all resources to `assets` folder when porting to Android project. However, I met a lot of problem. I solved a lot,like reading xml from assets and using tinyxml to parse. However, I still have a lot of problem like I cannot write to a xml file in assets. I cannot create a CCSprite with a png file under sub-folder in assets [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23007035/cannot-create-ccsprite-with-subfolder-png-when-port-to-android-application-with). I am confused should I put all file under assets or is there a solution to show me where to put all my resources in my Android project. Can I write to a file under assets?

I have add permission to Android project.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Did I miss some permission?

Answer (score 0):

`assets` folder is read only. You have to use `CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->getWritablePath()` to get writable path and append your file name to it. Then you can use `CCDictionary` to write simple key value type data. Here is a sample code.

```
CCDictionary *dict = CCDictionary::create();
CCString *value= CCString::create("value");
root->setObject(value, "key");

std::string writablePath = CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->getWritablePath();
std::string fullPath = writablePath + "myfile.plist";
if(dict->writeToFile(fullPath.c_str())) {
     CCLog("file saved at %s", fullPath.c_str());
}
delete dict;
dict = NULL;
```